# What is the necessarily and sufficient condition that prime number $p$ inert in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let m be integer. What is the necessarily and sufficient condition that prime number $p$ inert in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$ ?

I would like to prove infinitely many prime number inert in $K$, but at first step, I need to confirm the titled condition.

Comment: Assuming that $m$ is squarefree and that $p\ne 2$, the condition is that $x^2-m$ is irreducible modulo $p$. In other words, $\left(\frac mp\right)=-1$. The rest you can figure out using quadratic receprocity, and the final answer will be a congruence condition modulo $m$. This all follows from the Kummer-Dedekind theorem.

Comment: @DouglasMolin that question is talking about ramified primes, of which there are only finitely many, not inert primes, so it's not really related.